# How to make values of a particular column in SQL table as headers of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I have SQL database table as shown in the image. I want values of column **Location_Instance**(i.e., the second column in the image)  to to displayed as headers of a `GridView`. Right now I am copying the column the to a `ListBox` and using the `ListBox` to be displayed as headers. But I want to display directly from datasource. Can anyone kindly help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to show those column values in GridView?

Comment: I want to show column values as headers of `GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to write some additional code that creates a new DataTable with the columns set how you want, then insert rows how you want to, from the data in the database.

Doing it in SQL is difficult.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd.aspx for how to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly set the column's value as header in grid view, first you have to save it at some place  eg ViewState or any control

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing right now. But if I do that I am finding difficult in updating the `GridView` as the number of column generated in `GridView` are unknown every time.

Comment: Directly it is not possible, If you want to convert all of your rows to columns then you can use Pivot and there also other ways to convert rows to columns.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Select Query and Get the data

like

```
Select * from Tbl where 'Condition'
```

Fill the data in a datatable (ex: dt).
Then bind data directly to the gridview.
like

Gridview.Datasource = dt;
 Gridview.Databind();

Then Directly The headers will be displayed.

If you want to Display `Location_Type` as `Location Type` then you have to write SQL Query like this

```
Select Location_Type as [Location Type] .... from Tbl where 'Condition'
```

Comment: So will this set the headers of `GridView` as Bedroom1 Bedroom2 Kitchen1 etc...???

Comment: No. What do you need exactly? Do you want to set Header names as the data in location Instance column?? (like Header names are Bedroom1, Bedroom2,Kitchen1, Bathroom1 ...)????

Comment: Yes I want to set Header names as the data in location Instance column like Header names are Bedroom1, Bedroom2,Kitchen1, Bathroom1 ...

Answer (score 0):

Logically this is not possible. Because in this case you want to show rows of data in a single row with multiple column. SO in case your location instance increases what will you do??

But if the number of location_instance is fixed then there is a work around. But this is also limited. You can show the location instance as grid view row, not as column. You can style the row so that it will look like header.

To know how to convert a column data to a row data check the below link. 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

So once you get the data in a row you can bind the data to the grid view easily by using `RowDataBound` of grid view.